# How to selectively choose values in a composite key in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following csv files with 5 columns and a number of rows. But I'm showing only first 6 rows.

```
Date,Food,Vitamin,Protein,NumStudents
01/01/17, Pasta, A, Yes, 560
01/01/17, Pizza, A, Yes, 730
01/01/17, Burrito, C, Yes, 240
02/01/17, Pizza, A, Yes, 340
02/01/17, Pasta, B, Yes, 450
02/01/17, Beef, B, Yes, 450
```

Now I want to find the sum of NumStudents on a particular day who had only Pizza and Pasta.

In essence for `01/01/17` I only have to sum NumStudents for Pizza and Pasta but not Burrito.

Expected Output

```
01/01/17 1290
02/01/17 790
```

Output I'm getting

```
01/01/17 1530
02/01/17 1240
```

In my code I'm able to sum NumStudents for all 3 types of food but don't know how to selectively exclude some type of food from my composite key in mapper. Any idea how should I go about it?

Comment: Alex, I wrote a java 8 based answer (no hadoop): I had to remove it because you seem to be looking for a hadoop solution. Would the java 8 version works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter the types you're interested in, in the mapper. This could look something like:

```
public class InputMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private Text oKey = new Text();
    private IntWritable oValue = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
                            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String parts[] = value.toString().split(",");
        if (parts[1].equals("Pasta") || parts[1].equals("Pizza")) {
            oKey.set(parts[0]);
            oValue.set(Integer.parseInt(parts[4]));
            context.write(oKey, oValue);
        }
    }
}
```

So in the reduce you would just sum the values to get the total count and the key is the date.